# Can anyone explain HVDC transmission to me?

Tags: power-engineering, transmission, hvdc

HVDC transmission system sounds strange to me because I wonder why we would need it?

We have HVAC transmission system which is much more efficient and less power losses. When we use the DC for same application it may result in huge power losses and inefficiency.

Could someone explain to me why we employ HVDC transmission systems?

Comment: Why would it "... result in huge power losses and inefficiency"? Do you mean due to \$I^2R\$ losses? do consider that power is being transmitted at *High Voltage*. I think it mainly makes it harder to convert back to mains voltage AC.

Comment: What about inductance effects ? Greater with AC or DC ?

Comment: Also, with some research you can find pretty good explanations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current#Comparison_with_AC

Comment: if HVAC were really 'much more efficient', then people would stick to it. The entire reason some push to HVDC is because in some situations, it can be more efficient.

Comment: [Related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395481/what-is-the-maximum-voltage-that-silicon-can-handle/395504#395504). A lot of time it's to do with transmission of power to islands from the mainland where conventional wires cannot be used. There is a point where it becomes economical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> HVDC transmission system sounds strange to me because I wonder why we would need it?
>
> We have HVAC transmission system which is much more efficient and less power losses...

... less power losses ... than LVAC transmission

> When we use the DC for same application it may result in huge power losses and inefficiency.

It may, if you do it wrongly, like use too low a voltage. That's why it's called High Voltage DC.

> Could someone explain to me why we employ HVDC transmission systems?

There are three significant advantages of DC over AC, once the distance is long enough to absorb the extra capital cost of the conversion stations at each end

1) Better use of the conductor and the insulation. For any given peak voltage across the insulation, and current heating in the conductor, DC shifts more power than AC. The simplest way to see this is that AC is dropping to zero between cycles, DC stays at maximum. This translates into a lower cable cost for any given power flow.

2) No capacitive charging currents. Line charging requires current to be drawn, which causes losses in the line.

3) No synchronisation issues when exporting power between grids. It is possible to move AC power between unsynchronised grids, but that requires an investment in converters at each end of at least the size needed for HVDC power. International export and import of electricity is important now, and will become even  more so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the reasoning for HVDC: [High voltage electricity transport](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493081/high-voltage-electricity-transport/493102)

tl; dr version:

- no armor and dielectric losses in undersea / underground cables (the original reason)
- no skin effect => greater current capacity / lower IR drop
- eases frequency and voltage intertie issues